# Is it possible to clear the "Notifications" on Facebook for Android?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, notifications, facebook

I have **enabled notifications** in the 'Inbox' section of my **Facebook for Android** program.

**Does anyone know of a way to clear the 'Notifications' list ?**

*Reason I ask :* Every time I start up Facebook , I get the message that I have 4 new notifications. Over and over again , the same notifications.

Under Windows, these are the same four as I can see when clcking the world icon on top of the screen. However, on Windows, the world icon only lights up when a new notification has arrived, as soon as you click (or view) the notification, no visual indication is present any more.

So, I would like these notifications only to alert me, when new arrive, not every time.

**UPDATE:**

As it was, I was talking about the Samsung version of FB/ Android (Facebook S! version 1). I downloaded and installed the one from the Market, and this is much better.

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have? My notifications bar is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @ Al E.: Still learning my new phone (and first Android) : but I think it it 'Facebook D! version 1,  can I get some more specific version information ?

Comment: Either go to the "Downloads" section of the Market, find the app, and get the version number there, or go to "Settings | Applications | Manage applications | Facebook". (This latter is also where you would clear the cache.)

Comment: I updated my question - thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there doesn't appear to be a way to clear the notifications short of visiting the item so it is no longer new.

The Android Facebook app has a lot of deficits. It's still head-and-shoulders better than the previous version, though.

Comment: @Al E.: Visiting them doesn't clear them. That's the point , I don't mind visiting them if they are new.

Comment: Then I suggest your Facebook app is defective. They clear for me. Have you tried clearing the app cache?

Comment: @ Al E.: How do you clear the cache ? But to be sure we are talking about the same thing here : pressing the inbox button, show a list of 6 possible notifications. I am talking about the last one in that list : this number remains the same, whether I click on them and visit the notification there or not. The others, as requests and Updates and so on, do clear fine.

Comment: Again, what version of the Facebook app are you using? I don't have an "Inbox" and I'm running the latest version (1.3.2).

Comment: @ Al E.: I think I have one made by Samsung (that's why it says Facebook S! vesion 1 - I mistyped before and said Facebook D!).

Comment: @ Al E.: I downloaded FB for Android just now - it's much better than the one I had. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad we got it straightened out.

Answer (score 3):

"Facebook S! version 1" is Facebook for Samsung, available from the Samsung apps store on Samsung Android phones. This is their custom version of Facebook, not the standard Facebook for Android that's available from the Market, it is probably based on an older version of the Facebook app, and is definitely not the same as the current official Facebook app.

If you go to the Android Market, search for Facebook and download the app called "Facebook for Android" written by "Facebook" then you know that you have the latest official Facebook app. The notifications on that version go for me after I've visited them.

Also if for some reason you do prefer Samsung's app over Facebook's then you're running an older version of that, the current version (according to the Samsung Apps app on my Galaxy S) is 1.01 installing this updated version may fix some problems.